# Laravel Breeze and Spatie Permissions set role while user registered

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-permission

I'm using Laravel Breeze as an Auth scaffolding package alongside Laravel Permissions by Spatie. I have created two registration forms, one for "Student" and the other for "Teacher" all registration views are located in RegisteredUserController.

**app\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisteredUserController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Frontend\User;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class RegisteredUserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display the registration view for student.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function createSudent()
    {
        return view('auth.student.student-space');
    }
    
    /**
     * Display the registration view for teacher.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function createTeacher()
    {
        return view('auth.teacher.teacher-space');
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|confirmed|min:8',
        ]);

        Auth::login($user = User::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
        ]));
        
        // Create roles
        
        $create_sponsor_role = Role::create(['name' => 'student']);
        $create_project_role = Role::create(['name' => 'teacher']);
        
        // Assigning roles
        
        $user->assignRole(['student', 'teacher']);
        
        // Check if it's correct roles
        
        if($user()->hasRole('sponsor')) {
            return redirect()->intended('/student/dashboard');
        }
        
        if ($user()->hasRole('project')) {
            return redirect()->intended('/teacher/dashboard');
        }
        
        else {
            return redirect('/signin');
        }
        
        event(new Registered($user));
    }
}
```

As you can see in this controller, I have two registration views for two types of users **"Student"** and **"Teacher"**.

What I want to do is to Set **the role of the users** while registration based on these two types **"Student" and "Teacher"** Roles using **laravel-permission** by **spatie**.

**app\routes\auth.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisteredUserController;

Route::get('/student-space', [RegisteredUserController::class, 'createStudent'])->middleware('guest')->name('student-space');

Route::get('/teacher-space', [RegisteredUserController::class, 'createTeacher'])->middleware('guest')->name('teacher-space');
```

Comment: You should not create roles on every request for registration

Comment: I've spend two days with this problem try to fixed but nothing is work I wish if someone could help me

Comment: [I create this Gist can help you to understand](https://gist.github.com/devhoussam/1feef5e279b8acfc039d9d593740bdb6)

Answer (score 0):

Here I explain a simple setup for your purpose:

### Seed your roles

If you're using spatie laravel permission. At first, you need to have some roles in your database. It can be achieved by writing a crud and controlling it in the admin panel or seeding them in the database. Here I write seed for it.

For your case, I create two roles of *writer* and *publisher*:

1. Create *RoleTableSeeder* seeder by running `php artisan make:seeder RoleTableSeeder`
2. Call the seeder in the *Database\Seeders\DatabaseTableSeeder* like below:

```
namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call(RoleTableSeeder::class);
    }
}
```

3. Write roles in your seeder like below:

```
namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class RoleTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        $writerRole = Spatie\Permission\Models\Role::create([
            'name'         => 'writer'
        ]);

        $publisherRole = Spatie\Permission\Models\Role::create([
            'name'         => 'publisher'
        ]);
    }
}
```

4. Run the seeder by calling `php artisan db:seed`

### Register users and giving roles

You should direct your users to the correct view blade as you did in the question.
Roles must be assigned to users after their creation. Here you need a logic for discrimination between whether it is a *writer* or a *publisher*? I suggest putting a hidden input in your form for role. If it is true, you can specify for example *writer* role and make some fields as required using `required_if`method explained here.

You should give user a role after creation.

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'name'         => 'required|string|max:255',
        'custom_field' => [Rule::requiredIf($request->role)],
        'email'        => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password'     => 'required|string|confirmed|min:8',
    ]);

    Auth::login($user = User::create([
        'name'     => $request->name,
        'email'    => $request->email,
        'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
    ]));

    $role = $request->get('role')
        ? Spatie\Permission\Models\Role::findByName('writer')
        : Spatie\Permission\Models\Role::findByName('publisher');

    $user->assignRole($role);

    event(new Registered($user));

    return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
}
```

Comment: Error **Class "App\Models\Role" not found** after registration an account as "Writer"

Comment: I don't want to use **Seeds** from database I want to create my own credentials by using registration form

Comment: Use Spatie Role Class. I've updated the answer.

Comment: You should add the roles to the database. By seeding or other ways you prefer

Comment: thank you for help but **return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);** it's only for one register form for the "Writer" not "Publisher"

Comment: I want the route for the publisher too after success registration it will redirect to the dashboard based on what register form are used

Comment: You can redirect them to wherever you want.  *RouteServiceProvider::HOME* is just an address.

Comment: if User choose to register as "Writer" redirect him/her to **return redirect(/writer/dashboard);**
if User choose to register as "Publisher" redirect him/her to **return redirect(/publisher/dashboard);** How can I achieve that in registerController and sorry to botter you my fr'iend

Comment: Still looking for solution to my problem

Comment: I've written a long and descriptive answer for you. You should work on the basics of laravel and programming paradigm. Redirecting users is very complex ;)

Comment: I try the solution but it not working for me I have updated my code I will update the question

Comment: My Question is Updated